# Java - why doesn't jstack work in a tight loop

Tags: java, jstack

I've noticed that jstack doesn't work when code is in a tight loop.

For example in this code:

```
private static void testAllocationNotOnHeap(){
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long result =0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 20_000; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
            result += new TestObject(5,5).getResult();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Allocation not on heap took "
            + (System.currentTimeMillis()-time)
            + " with result " + result);
}
```

If you run jstack you get this message:

> Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
>   The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding

As soon as you allow the code to 'breathe' e.g. by add a System.out every few thousand iterations it all works fine.

Note this is the same if you want to run jconsole or flight recorder from jmc.

I'd like to understand why this is and if there's anything I can do about it as I'd like to profile a tight loop.

Comment: It could be that the `write()` method on `System.out` [is internally synchronized](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.write%28java.lang.String%29), which causes some side-effect that allows the external program to attach to the process.  If that's the case, then in theory placing any `synchronized` block in the inner loop would also work.

Comment: I've been doing some research on this and I suspect it's because the code never reaches a safepoint.  Related to this article I wrote: http://www.rationaljava.com/2015/05/safepoints-strange-and-dangerous.html